# One lowercase letter in chapter name

Tags: chapters

I have a chapter title which has an abbreviation inside. The chapter title in the class is all written in uppercase letters, but the plural suffix of the abbreviation should be in lowercase. How can I do this?

E.g.:

```
\chapter{Bla Bla Bla Bla XYZs}
```

gives

```
BLA BLA BLA BLA XYZS
```

but what I want is:

```
BLA BLA BLA BLA XYZs
```

MWE:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}
\usepackage{environ,amssymb}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hangcaption}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

%if you're having problems with overfull boxes, you may need to increase
%the tolerance to 9999
\tolerance=9999

\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}

\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\singlespacing\hangcaption{#1}\normalspacing}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\plural}{s}

\title {XXX}
\author {xxx}
\conferraldate {September}{2014}
\degreefield {asda}
\copyrightholder{asdasd}
\copyrightyear{2014}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\makecopyright


\begin{statement}

\end{statement}

\begin{abstract2}


\end{abstract2}

\begin{acknowledgements}

\end{acknowledgements}

\contentspage
\tablelistpage
\figurelistpage

\normalspacing \setcounter{page}{1} \pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{cornell} \addtolength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\chapter{Bla Bla Bla Bla XYZs}
```

Edit:

Template used: http://www.gradschool.cornell.edu/sites/default/files/field_file/cu_thesis-2.9.zip

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a full MWE which shows this behaviour to us. Like this, we will have to try around until we find your very case, giving us much more work. You should always show, what you have (as short as possible), what you have tried, and where you are running into problems. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say `\DeclareRobustCommand{\plural}{s}` in the preamble and `\chapter{Bla XYZ\plural}`, but some more information is needed.

Comment: `\MakeUppercase{Bla Bla Bla Bla XYZ\MakeLowercase{s}}` works, so you might be lucky with `\MakeLowercase{s}` if your headings are defined with `\MakeUppercase{#1}`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, the command you wrote is working!! Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Unfortunately I tried this, but did not work because, I am using Cornell University template and it seems they have defined it as something else.

Comment: The MWE you provided is useless; can you point to the template you're using instead?

Comment: @www Good to hear that egregs version works. But this is the reason why we need an MWE. The snippet you posted does not compile and does not show your upper-case headings. That's why we need to guess around and provide wrong answers (like mine) and it costs us time which you should've spent preparing the example.

Comment: @egreg I updated the question with the template.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I had 90 pages and could not reduce the size, but updated the question right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\plural}{s}
```

in your document preamble and use

```
\chapter{Bla Bla Bla Bla XYZ\plural}
```

so the uppercasing macros will not change `\plural` and a lowercase “s” will appear.

Remember to use `{}` after `\plural` in case you want to preserve a following space, such as in

```
\chapter{Bla XYZ\plural{} Bla}
```